# Apache: Remove index.php from url after Query Params

Tags: apache-http-server, php, httpd

I want to remove `index.php` from my URL after Query Params.

This is My Url:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/report?user=USERNAME
```

I have removed Query Params and convert it into Pretty Url using:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user=
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(.*)$ $2?user=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ ?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, My URL looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/report/USERNAME
```

So all the requests to this URL will point to the entry script of my project i.e. `web/index.php`.

When I use below routes to get data, it works:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/report/Default/index.php/api/registration/user-registrations/
```

But when I remove `index.php` from URL and access it like below, it throws 404.

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/report/Default/api/registration/user-registrations/
```

FYI, I am using Symfony for routing all my routes.

I am stuck in this from the past 2 weeks. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have no rule to rewrite the URL without index.php into a URL with!

As you say, the URL which works (#1) is:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/report/Default/index.php/api/registration/user-registrations/
```

And the URL you want to get to work (#2) is:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/report/Default/api/registration/user-registrations/
```

The goal of a rewrite is to help the server understand what a URL means so that it can serve it correctly. So, you need a rule to rewrite #2 into #1.

Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(/user/report/Default)/(.*)$ $1/index.php/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Please note that I haven't tested this so you may need to experiment a little. It's possible that you might need to remove the 'L' flag.

**Edit**

Here's a more full example, showing how you can use RewriteRules to build up to what you want, as they run in sequence.

I've modified your rewrite rule - rather than using a-zA-Z0-9-, which would not match index.php, i just match the last part of the URL. Regular expression syntax is tricky and worth getting to grips with, but I appreciate it's a difficult topic.

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user= 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php$1?user=$2 [QSA,L]
```

This sort of thing should work.

(for anyone coming to this reply fresh, i iterated on the rules directly with the question asker in order to clarify the setup.)

Comment: The problem is `USERNAME` is dynamic so I can't directly rewrite rule like you said `^(/user/report/Default)/(.*)$`.

Comment: It's no problem at all. RewriteRules run in sequence. I'll add a more full example to my answer.

Comment: Here Username is `Default`. So it will be different every time. Like `http://127.0.0.1/user/report/Akshay` and `http://127.0.0.1/user/report/Ben`.

Comment: i had to take a guess at the relationship between "user/report/Default/api/registration" and "user/report/USERNAME". I assumed that /user/report/Default was just where the files were uploaded to, and all of the rewriting was on parts after that. If that's not the case, please can you clarify the before-and-after that you need.

Comment: okay - and where do you need index.php to go? AFTER the username?

Comment: `index.php` should not be there at all. #2 URL should work. It is showing 404 currently.

Comment: I'm sorry let me clarify. The aim of a rewrite rule is to take a "nice" URL that you want end users to see, and convert it into a "nasty" url behind the scenes, which Apache understands. The nasty url remains hidden, but I need to know what it should be. We need to include index.php somewhere, behind the scenes. for this to work.

Comment: Yes So it will be after Username i.e. `http://127.0.0.1/user/report/Default/index.php/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108126/discussion-between-ben-xo-and-akshaypjoshi).